# Complexity of this implementation of countsort

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

What is the complexity of the below implementation of countsort?

```
void countSort(vector<int>& input)
{
    map<int, int> freq;
    for (int x: input) {
        freq[x]++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (auto p: freq)
    {
        while (p.second--) {
            input[i++] = p.first;
        }
    }
}
```

Someone told me it's O(n). Doesn't this `for`,

```
for (int x: input) {
        freq[x]++;
    }
```

make it O(n log n) cause map container in C++ is a balanced BST, and Insert operation is O(log n) ?

Comment: Yup, not a very good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Countsort is a *linear* sorting algorithm. Usually linear sorting algorithms have some kind of limitation that allows them to be linear in return to not being completely generic.

In this case the limitation is that it sorts non-negative (you can expand it to *any* and still keep it linear) integers, and counts them using the values as keys in the *array* of frequencies.

Using [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead of an array defeats the purpose. It makes the implementation generic, but then no longer linear.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-counting-sort-using-map-in-c/ Here it says it's O(n), that's why I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Red-black tree has amortized complexity of O(1) for insert operation, which is why they're saying that. But in the worst case it's O(log(n))

Comment: So isn't it still O(n) then ?

Comment: I added a link to the description of map::insert on cppreference. You can see in what cases you can treat it as O(1) and in what you shouldn't. The way the code is written in your sample, by spec you should assume O(log(n)) complexity.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning, that countsort is linear both on the input and the range of the input (*O(n+k)*, where *n* is the size of the input, and *k* is the difference between min and max in the input). So it should really be used for sorting an array of close in value integers, otherwise your linear complexity may be more than a logarithmic complexity of a general algorithm due to the large value of *k*.